# Jenkins build scripts when getting project from git

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am building and compiling a project using jenkins from a git sources, everytime I change my code on git, I will go to jenkins and build the project, the problem is that, for each code changes I delte the directory in jenkins , and again clone from github and use the maven install command for building my project, the build script in my jenkins setting page is as follow:

```
rm -r /home/jenkins/gcp-ingestion
cd /home/jenkins
git clone https://github.com/Bazarganigilani/gcp-ingestion.git
cd /home/jenkins/gcp-ingestion
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

I wonder if there is any better approach so I don't have to delete the project directory and clone it for each minor changes in my git repo?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it could be a `cron` job

There are plugins for git/github and maven which you can leverage. These will abstract the git commands and maven interaction.

Checkout this [tutorial](https://huongdanjava.com/build-maven-project-in-jenkins.html) as a start

To be current with Jenkins, you probably want to keep a [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/) in your repo and keep the configuration there

Comment: Not sure, if anyone answered my question here, I asked if there is a better way to not delete all my project directories' contents and again clone them when I build my updated project either by my own or by triggers in jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cron job, there is provision in jenkins option called `build trigger`.

so that build could get triggered automatically when you push the code to the corresponding branch.